# rCharts HighCharts how to color zones

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am running into a problem where I cannot color different sections of a graph I am working on. I want to change the color based on the threshold on the y axis. It seems easy from looking at the documentation from the high charts javascript, but it fails when I try to translate it into R to use rCharts. Here is what I have, with an example data frame called final.

```
library(rCharts)
final <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(15,17,20,21,22), radius = rep(3,5))
temp <- apply(final[,c("x","y","radius"])], 1, as.list)
a <- Highcharts$new()
a$series(animation = FALSE, name = "placeholder", data = temp, type = "scatter", 
lineWidth = 1, zoneAxis = "y", zones = list(list(value = 20, 
                                                 color = "rgba(223, 83, 83, 0.5)"),
                                            list(color = "rgba(50, 205, 50, 0.5)")))
```

This does not change the plot from the default color, so I'm very confused and would greatly appreciate any help or possibly another solution. Thanks!

This is modeled off of the documentation for zones here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#4aaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the points I do not understand:
This code has a `]` inside the `c()` without a sense;

```
temp <- apply(final[,c("x","y","radius"])], 1, as.list)
```

Your intent I guess, was to select all columns, which can be achieved with a simple:

```
temp <- apply(final[ , ], 1, as.list)
```

But this code also seems to be strange for me because the same results can be obtained with just:

```
temp <- apply(final, 1, as.list)
temp
[[1]]
[[1]]$x
[1] 1

[[1]]$y
[1] 15

[[1]]$radius
[1] 3


[[2]]
[[2]]$x
[1] 2

[[2]]$y
[1] 17

[[2]]$radius
[1] 3


[[3]]
[[3]]$x
[1] 3

[[3]]$y
[1] 20

[[3]]$radius
[1] 3


[[4]]
[[4]]$x
[1] 4

[[4]]$y
[1] 21

[[4]]$radius
[1] 3


[[5]]
[[5]]$x
[1] 5

[[5]]$y
[1] 22

[[5]]$radius
[1] 3
```

If of course you wanted that.

#### Edit: Color changed (another approach)

I changed the color even though I have to admit I achieved this solution due to my ignorance of which package the `rgba` functions belongs to.
I change the `rgba` to `rgb`, I have unquoted it (are you sure it should be quoted?) and I set the `max = 255` to the `rgb`. Here is the code.

```
a$series( animation = FALSE, name = "placeholder",
            data = temp, type = "scatter",
            lineWidth = 1, zoneAxis = "y",
            zones = list(list(value = 20,
                        color = rgb(223, 83, 83, 0.5, max = 255)),
                      list(color = rgb(50, 205, 50, 0.5, max = 255))
                      )
            )
```

Comment: Sorry yeah that was a typo. I did not make that typo when I did it locally, so I get the same thing as you for output of temp. I just can't get the zones to color correctly. Not sure if there's a solution. It would also be interesting if I could color each point individually if you know how that would be possible. Thank you.

Comment: Hey SabDem, sorry I didn't check this post in awhile. I will accept the answer! Thanks!